# What are various factors to be considered for Font Selection Parameters for any applications?

Tags: gui-design, ux-field, user-centered-design, ux-designer, font

I am sure there are multiple parameters and factors to be considered while selecting a font, for the application to be designed and developed. Few of the points that are straight away taken into consideration are Brand Tone, What the application is about, Market, Voice etc.

These are business aspects of the considerations, however there are other technical considerations to be made is what I am assuming like letter spacing etc.

Requesting the community to add more to this.

Comment: Most people don't notice fonts.  They might be aware of serif versus sans-serif, or narrow versus wide spacing, but the average person won't notice the difference between a blog typeset in Arial and one typeset in Frutiger (and a substantial fraction won't notice the difference between Papyrus and Comic Sans).

Answer (score 4):

The four basic elements to consider when choosing a font are: x-height, width, special characters and number of styles.

### Readability

Based on the design of the app/web, choose fonts with better legibility. The higher the x-height, the better its reading and vice versa:

[image]

### Space

Depending on the amount of text, if the app or website has a lot of text, choose fonts that in their normal version allow you to place the largest number of characters per line. A font with a narrower counter in its normal version is always better than scaling part of the text horizontally.

[image: counter]

### Functionality

Choose fonts that have the most characters, you never know when you will need to use some of them. As an example, containing all, or the greatest number, of currency symbols: € ¥ £

### Practicality

Most fonts have only four styles: normal, italic, bold, and bold italic. I personally discard these fonts for text, always choosing the ones that offer the most styles.

[image: styles]

<sub>*All examples are from [Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/?preview.text=Lorem%20ipsum&preview.text_type=custom)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

When choosing a font for an application, consider the following factors:

1. Readability: Ensure the font is clear and easy to read.
2. Font Size: Select an appropriate size for different devices.
3. Typeface and Style: Choose a typeface that matches the application's theme and audience.
4. Font Weight: Use different weights to create visual contrast.
5. Line Spacing: Maintain proper spacing between lines for readability.
6. Kerning: Adjust the space between characters for better legibility.
7. Character Set and Language Support: Confirm font supports required characters and languages.
8. Screen Resolution and Size: Consider target devices and their resolutions.
9. Accessibility: Ensure the font meets accessibility guidelines.
10. Typeface Pairing: If using multiple fonts, ensure they complement each other.
11. Loading Time: Check font loading time for web applications.
12. Licensing and Cost: Use fonts with appropriate licensing.
13. Brand Consistency: Align the font with the overall brand guidelines.